# Prestashop - setting product weight

Tags: php, prestashop

Could anybody explain me how can I set product weight before adding it to cart?

I'm trying to clone default product attribute from `ps_product_attribute`, than change weight and add this to cart via `$this->context->cart->updateQty($quantity, $id_product, $id_product_attribute)`.

After that I have this product in a cart but price is always 0,00 $. How can I set weight dynamically via PHP?

Answer (score -1):

You can trying something like

```
 $id_product = Tools::getValue('id_product');
 $product = Product((int)$id_product);
 $product->width ='width value';
 $product->update();
```